# Hiding Log Out Nav button on Log in page Vue JS

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a simple VueJS Web app with firebase and firebase authentication (email-password). Authentication part works great, however, I don't want to have Log Out button in my Nav bar on the Log in screen(or sign up screen for that matter).
I've set up a function in loginScreen.vue that checks whether user is logged in (if no user is logged in it is null) so it is:

```
        created () { 
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
           if (user != null) {
                console.log('no null')
                // reference to #routerbtn .show
            } else {
                console.log('yes null')
                // reference to #routerbtn .hide
            }
          }
```

This console.log output is just to check whether it works. But I can't find the way to reference the `<li>` from navHeader in order to hide it on the page.  Navigation is in navHeader.vue through `<router-link>` only logout is just `<li>` This is navHeader.vue

```
<template>
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><router-link to="/home" exact>To Do</router-link></li>
    <li><router-link to="/done" exact>Done</router-link></li>
    <li><router-link to="/inprogress" exact>In Progress</router-link> 
</li>
    <li id="#routerbtn" v-on:click="logout">Log Out</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default {

methods: {

    logout: function () {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
        this.$router.replace('login')
    })
}
}
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions, cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your created method change to:

```
created () { 
  this.user = firebase.auth().currentUser || false;
}
```

Also make sure `user` is in your `data` method.

Then check user in your view.

```
<ul>
    ...
    <li v-if="user">Log Out</li>
    <li v-else>Register</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

---

As you go on, you want to abstract out the menu into a component so you're not repeating this same code throughout each page.

Comment: Hm, I can't get it to work with this. I believe the issue is that the nav bar is in a separate .vue file - navHeader.vue, while I need to run a function that checks whether the user is logged within the loginScreen.vue. 

Do I need to use eventBus with $emit and $on to communicate between these two sibling components?

Comment: You don't need an event bus, you could just make a [plugin](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html), this is what I do, then instead of accessing `this.user` it would be a global `this.$user` prop. Or you could use the store.